# Какие есть форумы где обсуждаются вопросы кибербезопасности где эти вопросы можно задать самому?

Tags: безопасность, kali-linux, сетевое-программирование

Поискал в интернете ничего годного не нашел. Мне нужны сайты, чаты или форумы, где можно задать вопрос про кибербезопасность. Где сидят не липовые пентестеры, а люди которые этим занимаются и хорошо разбираются в своем деле? Кто знает - посоветуйте пожалуйста

Comment: На StackExchange есть пару таких сайтов. Посмотрите в списке. А "пентестеры" есть везде)

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Да, и вот тоже: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://serverfault.com/tour

Comment: @user207200, этот-то сайт при чем?

Comment: @Глеб как причем? Самый что ни на есть прикладной уровень ИБ.

Comment: @user207200 Ну, кибербезопасность, по-моему, "not directly related to professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration" — из их Tour. Хотя я на этом сайте не работаю, точно не знаю.

Comment: А с доменом onion есть такие?

Comment: Не в курсе)  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯